# Transparent JDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, transparent, jdesktoppane

I would like to set the JDesktopPane to transparent and allow me to click through to what is underneath (e.g.. Desktop icons etc). The internal frame should be left opaque and able to be repositioned around the screen as it currently does. Any ideas?

```
    package test1;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;


    public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);


    JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
    JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Title", false, true, false, true);
    desktop.setBackground(Color.RED);  
    //desktop.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.0f));
    desktop.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.setBounds(25, 25, 200, 100);
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I figured this out. I changed Color.RED to new Color(0,0,0,0) and needed to also add frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0)); at the end. Hope that helps somebody.

Comment: Actually this only part worked, it is now transparent but I can't click through.

Comment: That's actually a really bad idea, Swing doesn't know how to paint opaque components which have a transparent  color, instead, you need to "fake" it, by making the component transparent and then overriding it's `paintComponent` method and using a `AlphaComposite`. This is further complicated by the fact that `JInternalFrame` has a `JRootPane` and `contentPane` which are also opaque

Comment: *"Actually this only part worked, it is now transparent but I can't click through"* - I think you'll find getting that to work is far more difficult then it sounds

Answer (score 4):

## Part #1 Translucent `JInternalFrame`

Creating a translucent component is more involved then just setting the background color to an alpha based value.

Swing only knows how to paint either opaque or fully transparent components, the API is also optimised in such away that if it's updating an opaque component, it won't update the area of the parent behind the component.  Using an alpha based color will generate all kinds of nasty paint artifacts

Instead, you need to "fake" it.  This involves setting the component to be fully overriding the components `paint` method and using a `AlphaComposite` to generate the translucent effect (normally I'd use the `paintComponent` method, but you have to remember that that would leave the child components unaffected)

[image: Desktop]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JDesktopPane dp = new BackgroundDesktopPane();

                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\shane\\Dropbox\\Ponies\\SmallPony.png"));

                    TransparentInternalFrame iframe = new TransparentInternalFrame("Banana", true, true, true, true);
                    iframe.setLocation(10, 10);
                    iframe.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
                    iframe.pack();
                    iframe.setVisible(true);

                    dp.add(iframe);


                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(dp);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TransparentInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        public TransparentInternalFrame() {
            super();
        }

        public TransparentInternalFrame(String title) {
            super(title);
        }

        public TransparentInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable) {
            super(title, resizable);
        }

        public TransparentInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable) {
            super(title, resizable, closable);
        }

        public TransparentInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable, boolean maximizable) {
            super(title, resizable, closable, maximizable);
        }

        public TransparentInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable, boolean maximizable, boolean iconifiable) {
            super(title, resizable, closable, maximizable, iconifiable);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.25f));
            super.paint(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public class BackgroundDesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public BackgroundDesktopPane() throws IOException {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\shane\\Dropbox\\Ponies\\800px-Rainbow_Dash_flying_past_1_S2E16.png"));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight()); 
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }



    }

}
```

## Part #2 Click through...

Providing the ability to click through the components is a lot more difficult and becomes a lot more difficult if you add components which support mouse events.  The following will allow mouse events to "fall through" the component (expect the frame boards), but any component in the internal frame which responds to mouse events will stop this from working.

[image: Click Through]

```
public class TransparentInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    public TransparentInternalFrame() {
        super();
        setOpaque(false);
        init();
    }

    public TransparentInternalFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        setOpaque(false);
        init();
    }

    public TransparentInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable) {
        super(title, resizable);
        setOpaque(false);
        init();
    }

    public TransparentInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable) {
        super(title, resizable, closable);
        setOpaque(false);
        init();
    }

    public TransparentInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable, boolean maximizable) {
        super(title, resizable, closable, maximizable);
        setOpaque(false);
        init();
    }

    public TransparentInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable, boolean maximizable, boolean iconifiable) {
        super(title, resizable, closable, maximizable, iconifiable);
        setOpaque(false);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        MouseAdapter proxy = new MouseAdapter() {

            protected void dispatchEventToParent(MouseEvent e) {
                Container parent = getParent();
                if (parent != null) {
                    e = SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(e.getComponent(), e, parent);
                    parent.dispatchEvent(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatchEventToParent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatchEventToParent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
                dispatchEventToParent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatchEventToParent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatchEventToParent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatchEventToParent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatchEventToParent(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                dispatchEventToParent(e);
            }

        };

        addMouseListener(proxy);
        addMouseMotionListener(proxy);
        addMouseWheelListener(proxy);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.25f));
        super.paint(g2d);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}

public class BackgroundDesktopPane extends JDesktopPane {

    private BufferedImage background;
    private List<Point> points;

    public BackgroundDesktopPane() throws IOException {
        points = new ArrayList<>(25);
        background = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\shane\\Dropbox\\Ponies\\800px-Rainbow_Dash_flying_past_1_S2E16.png"));
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                points.add(e.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return background == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (background != null) {
            int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
        }

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (Point p : points) {
            g2d.fillOval(p.x - 5, p.y - 5, 10, 10);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I only started with Java this morning, so I will experiment with your code.

Comment: Well, you adventuring into some very advance concepts within the API, which might be better left until you have a better understanding of the basics